# What method is best for importing products in bulk. Magmi or Magento's API?

Tags: import, magento-1.9, magmi

I would like to know which of the following methods for bulk importing is best.

Magmi or using Magento's API.

I am currently using Magmi. I am writing a script for bulk import in Vb.net using the Soap API, but before I waste anymore of my time I want to know if Magmi is the absolute best way to import. If so I will just stick with that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Steven Lynn**, I shall recommend to you Magmi is the better than Magento's API. Because Magento's API takes to times.

Comment: Good enough for me. I tested my script and you are correct. Magmi is the king of importing.